# How to instance a parent class without using DI

Tags: php, singleton

I am trying out a MVC concept where the main model for a database stems or trees off other models. I wanted to have a main database sort of model which does the connecting and queries. Then, other models are built to support the controller. Ie, a product model can be extended off the main database model to then query rather than using dependency injection.

My current ideology and attempt looks like this for the main database model:

```
namespace Portfolio\Application;

abstract class DriverModel {

    private static  $driver;
    private         $entity;

    private function __construct() {
        // Connection to the PDO will be done in here
    }

    private function __clone() {}

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(self::$driver)
            return self::$driver;

        self::$driver = new self();
        return self::$driver;
    }

    protected function q($sql, $values = []) {
        $stmt = $this->entity->Prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($values);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

Then my example profile controller would look something like this (having the methods to use the main database to run queries):

```
class ProfileModel extends DriverModel {
    public function doSomeQ() {
        $this->q('SELECT fname FROM users WHERE id = ?', [(int)1]);
    }
}
```

However, When I execute this line of code:

```
print_r(ProfileModel::getInstance()->doSomeQ());
```

I am left with this error: (which makes sense.)

> Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class.

I then remove the abstract attribute from the class (`class DriverModel`) but now, the instance I am receiving is the instance from the parent class meaning if I do a `print_r()` on the `getInstance()` method to the `ProfileModel`, there is no `doSomeQ()` method.

Any help on achieving this methodology would be helpful.

Comment: Stop using singletons, stop abusing inheritance and stop referring to active-record instances as "models". An learn to use dependency injection.

Comment: I don't program as a job, I'm in the Armed Forces buddy. This is a Hobby so rather than throwing attitude at me, ivah don't comment or explain how to do it. @tereško

Comment: And this is not how you ask someone to explain more. Buddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `get_called_class()` method instead of `new self();`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php

Attached you can find sample who show your expected behaviour

```
class Main {
    public static function getInstance() {
        $class = get_called_class();
        return new $class();
    }
}
class Foo extends Main{

}

var_dump(Foo::getInstance()); // Output Foo object
```

Comment: I got it working - https://3v4l.org/cLLgs now I can have multiple extending models treeing from a main model.